# Perl's foreach with string argument

Tags: perl

Perldocs only indicate that `foreach` loops "iterates over a normal list value" https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops, but I sometimes see them with string arguments, such as the following examples:

```
foreach (`curl example.com 2>/dev/null`) {
    # iterates 50 times
}

foreach ("foo\nbar\nbaz") {
    # iterates just 1 time. Why?
}
```

Is the behavior of passing a string like this defined? Separately, why the disparate results from passing the string returned by a backticked command, and a literal string, as in the example?

Comment: `for (split /^/m, $file_contents)` will get you what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scalar context, backticks return a single scalar containing all the output of the enclosed command. But `foreach (...)` evaluates the backticks in list context, which will separates the output into a list with one line per element.

Answer (score 3):

The question revolves around the [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), a critical concept for many things in Perl.

The `foreach` loop needs a list to iterate over, so it imposes the list context to build the [list values](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) you saw mentioned in docs. The list may be formed with literals, `qw(a b c)`, and may have one element; this is your second example, where one string is given, forming the one-element list that is iterated over.

The list can also come from an expression, that is evaluated in the list context; this is your first example. Many operations yield different returns based on context, and `qx` is such an operator as explained in mob's answer. This is something to note and be careful with. An expression may also return a single value regardless of context; then it is simply used to populate the list.

Comment: Thanks, this was my confusion. I had some overly simple assumptions about how Perl enforces context.

Comment: cf. `print join ":", localtime` and `print join ":", scalar localtime` or even `print join ":", sub{wantarray ? (1,2,3) : "scalar" }->()`

Answer (score 1):

From `perldoc -f qx`:

> In list context, returns a list of lines (however you've defined lines with $/ or $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR), or an empty list if the command failed.

From `perldoc perlsyn`:

> **Compound statements**
>
> [...]
>
> LABEL foreach VAR (LIST) BLOCK

Answer (score -2):

A string is not a list. If you want to iterate over the characters in a string you'll need

```perl
foreach my $character (split('', "foo\nbar\nbaz")) {
```

I think you might be confusing Perl with Python:

```python
>>> for c in "foo\nbar\nbaz":
...    print c
... 
f
o
.... remainder deleted ....
a
z
>>>
```

As pointed out by the other answers backticks/`qx{}` return a list of output lines from the executed command in list context.

Comment: `foreach ("foo") { ... }` is perfectly valid Perl, looping over the single-element list `("foo")`.